# Stop Typescript from emitting @class comments

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

In my project, the Typescript compiler compiles my classes like so:

```
class Example
{
    ...
}
```

into:

```
var Example = /** @class */ (function () {
  function Example() {
  }
  return Example;
}());
```

How can I configure Typescript (currently using VS2015) so that it doesn't emit that @class comment?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove just the `/** @class */` comment. I checked the source code and it does not seem to be controlled by any special compiler flag. The only way to remove this comment is to remove all comments, using the `--removeComments` compiler option.

Comment: This is very weird, though, because I'm sharing my project with another developer, and his emitted code *does not have this comment*. (And the reason I asked was to avoid this conflict.) Maybe we're using different versions, which I will have to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I'm using TypeScript SDK 2.3, there are no `/** @class */` comments.
It seems that after TypeScript SDK 2.5 will generate [these annotation comments](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#type-assertioncast-syntax-in-checkjsts-check-mode).

You can download TypeScript SDK (including old versions) from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258).